# Choosing textures in open GL

Tags: opengl, textures

Hi guys and girls the problem I have is I have sucessfully loaded 3 BMP textures (or at least I hope I have using `char* textureFilenames[textureCount] = {"cement.bmp","hedge.bmp","sky.bmp"};`
and I'm applying it currently using

```
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(-150.0, 0.0, -150.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f(-150.0, 0.0, 150.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
    glVertex3f(150.0, 0.0, 150.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
    glVertex3f(150.0, 0.0, -150.0);
```

however it currently only picks up the sky.bmp is there anyway i can select one of the others?

Comment: Is there any reason, why you create a new Stackoverflow user for each question? I mean, your question contains a snippet of code also found in http://stackoverflow.com/q/5388799/524368 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5384206/524368 -- you're clearly the same person.

Comment: possible duplicate of [opengl texturing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380717/opengl-texturing)

Comment: Didn't notice all of the dupes before I answered :/

Comment: nope nothing to do with me probably someone on the same course as me

Comment: You were handed this code in some course? Seriously? Oh my! Please tell your instructor to contact me, as I think he/she needs some clarification, too.

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL is a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine).  The current texture is part of the OpenGL state.  The last texture you bind with [glBindTexture()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindTexture.xml) will be used until you bind another.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cement_texture_id);

// ... following geometry will use the cement texture

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hedge_texture_id);

// ... hedge texture

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sky_texture_id);

// ... sky texture
```

The "[OpenGL RedBook](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/)" has [a chapter](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/chapter09.html) on texture mapping that covers the basics.

Comment: Judging by the code in the rest of the dupes, you've got an array of texture ids in `GLuint theTexture[textureCount]`

Answer (score 1):

You mistake lies in your lack of understanding of OpenGL. **OpenGL is not a scene graph!** It's best to think OpenGL to be a set of drawing tools to paint on a canvas called the frame buffer.

So in using OpenGL you must put your mind in a state similar to if you's draw a picture with pencils, eraser, brush and paint. First you prepare your tools: Textures are like "sheets of colour", meshes of vertices are like some delicate "brush".

Like an artist the very fist step is to prepare your tools. You prepare your geometry (i.e. the meshes), if you use Vertex Buffer Objects you load them into fast memory with glBufferData, and your paint and dye, the textures. This is what you do in the "init" phase (I prefer to do this on demand, so that users don't see a "loading" screen).

First you load all your objects (geometry in VBOs, textures etc.); you do this exactly once for each required object, i.e. once an object is prepared (i.e. complete) you don't have to re-upload it.

Then in every drawing iteration for each object you want to draw you bind the needed OpenGL *objects* to their *targets*, then perform the drawing calls, which will then be performed using the currently bound objects.

i.e. something like this, please use common sense to fill in the lacking functions in your mind:

```
struct texture; // some structure holding texture information, details don't matter here
struct geometry; // structure holding object geometry and cross references

texture *textures;
geometry *geometries;

texture * load_texture(char const *texture_name)
{
    texture *tex;

    if( texture_already_loaded(textures, texture_name) )
        tex = get_texture(texture_name);
    else
        tex = load_texture_data(textures, texture_name);

    return tex;
}

geometry * load_geometry(char const *geometry_name)
{
    geometry * geom;

    if( geometry_already_loaded(geometries, geometry_name) )
        geom = get_geometry(geometry_name);
    else
        geom = load_geometry_data(geometries, geometry_name)

    if( geom->texture_name )
        geom->texture = load_texture(geom->texture_name);

    return geom;
}

void onetime_initialization()
{
    for(geometry_list_entry * geom = geometry_name_list; geom ; geom = geom->next)
        geom->geometry = geometry_load(geom->name);
}

void drawGL()
{
    glViewport(...);
    glClearColor(...);
    glClear(...);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    // ...

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // ...

    for(geometry_list_entry * geom = geometry_name_list; geom ; geom = geom->next)
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // this is not redundant!
        glPushMatrix();

        apply_geometry_transformation(geom->transformation); // calls the proper glTranslate, glRotate, glLoadMatrix, glMultMatrix, etc.

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, geom->texture->ID);
        draw_geometry(geom);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // this is not redundant!
        glPopMatrix();
    }

   // ...

   swapBuffers();
}
```